# working with XHTML in JBOSS Seam

Tags: xhtml

I have taken one `rich:panel` in XHTML and there are 2 `rich:tabs` in that `rich:panel`.

I create rich extendable table for those and mention width for each column in that table.
When I run for default window size it works well but if I minimize/maximize there occurs some problem in column width (all columns are collapsed).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to dynamic column size of datatable, don't put size of the column and use 100% datatable width. And also, the container component should not be use size. It will be better to use layout.